# what should I label this UI property group selection

Tags: user-interface

In my application my users can generate statements, monthly and weekly. I've recently been
asked to allow the users the capability to associate a customer with either weekly or monthly
but not both, to a customer. This then leads to...if a user selects a weekly customer and runs a monthly
statement, he or she, should be prompted that customer's statement cannot be generated and why.

My question: In the UI of the customer screen when editing a customer, should I label the choice option(s) as

1. Select the customer **Statement
   Frequency** [ monthly or weekly]?
2. Select the customer **Statement Type** [
   monthly or weekly]?

What giudelines do you follow to assist you when making such decisions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using **Statement Frequency**. Other choices might be **cycle** or **period**.

The rule of thumb should be to ask the user (product's *business* owner) what terms and wordings to use. It's not uncommon for business users to review all the terms and messages the application uses. That way the resulting product will speak the users' language.

The reason is that developer-invented terminology often leads to unintuitive UI. It may be perceived as clumsy, unfamiliar, or even incomprehensible by end-users. The worst case is bringing the software's *internal* terminology and mechanisms to the user interface.